# xamarin JSON ICollection serialization issue

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, json.net

I am trying to serialize an ICollection to JSON but it serializing them as null.

Message class with ICollection which fails.

```
public class Message
{
    [JsonProperty("Id")]
    public Guid MessageId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("From")]
    public MessageFrom From { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Text")]
    public string Text { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Attachments")]
    public ICollection<Attachment> Attachments { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("AddedTime")]
    public DateTime AddedTime { get; set; }
    public string AddedTimeString { get; set; }
    public string AddedTimeDataString { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("IsRead")]
    public bool IsRead { get; set; }

    public ChatMyMessageView CV { get; set; }

}
```

The Attachment class

```
public class Attachment
    {
        [JsonProperty("Id")]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("AttachmentType")]
        public AttachmentType Type { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("Content")]
        public string Content { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("Thumbnail")]
        public string Thumbnail { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("AddedDate")]
        public DateTimeOffset AddedDate { get; set; }      

        [JsonIgnore]
        public string Title { get; set; }
    }`
```

I am creating new Message object with correct params. I've double checked the Attachments count before serialization and it's always 1 or more.
[Here you can see it in debug mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkMtF.jpg)

Serialization looks like:

```
        using (var client = new HttpClient(new ModernHttpClient.NativeMessageHandler()))
            {
               client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", Settings.UserAccessToken);
               var json = await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(message, Formatting.None));    
               var content = new StringContent(json, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
               var response = await client.PostAsync(Urls.SendMessageChat, content);
            }
```

And I am getting next JSON:

```
{  
   "ChatId":"67ea15e7-c697-473f-8b8a-06be9ee9d72b",
   "isDirectChat":false,
   "Id":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
   "From":null,
   "Text":null,
   "Attachments":[],
   "AddedTime":"0001-01-01T00:00:00",
   "AddedTimeString":null,
   "AddedTimeDataString":null,
   "IsRead":false,
   "CV":null
}
```

Where we can see that there is no Attachments inside. What I am doing wrong?  I have really no idea why this doesn't work... Could any one help me, please ?

Answer (score 1):

Can you please share the actual JSON that you are expecting from client?

If you hit the url via browser or postman/fiddler what is the exact dataset(json) that you are getting.

There are couple of things I would try

1. Make the datatype `ICollection` to `IEnumerable` or `IList`
2. the line with `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(message, Formatting.None))` to

   `var result = await client.GetStringAsync(YOUR_SERVICE_URL)
   JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Message>(result)`

Comment: Thank you for your respond, I have tryed some of your idea, I am really appreciate for you answer. The issue was that by some magic function start doing another code wich resetting collection. This magic with async/await. That was realy undpredictable.